# Match the first 14 characters in one file to the first 14 character in another file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob

```
>>> import glob
>>> import os
>>> ws = r'C:\Users\maddy\Documents\20200506\CFSv2\pp'
>>> os.chdir(ws)

>>> ctl_files = glob.glob("daily_*.ctl")
>>> ctl_files
['daily_20200512.ctl', 'daily_20200519.ctl', 'daily_20200526.ctl', 'daily_20200602.ctl', 'daily_20200609.ctl', 'daily_20200616.ctl', 'daily_20200623.ctl', 'daily_20200630.ctl', 'daily_20200707.ctl', 'daily_20200714.ctl', 'daily_20200721.ctl', 'daily_20200728.ctl', 'daily_20200804.ctl', 'daily_20200811.ctl', 'daily_20200818.ctl', 'daily_20200825.ctl', 'daily_20200901.ctl']
>>> bin_files = glob.glob("daily_*.bin")
>>> bin_files
['daily_20200421.bin', 'daily_20200428.bin', 'daily_20200505.bin', 'daily_20200512.bin', 'daily_20200519.bin', 'daily_20200526.bin', 'daily_20200602.bin', 'daily_20200609.bin', 'daily_20200616.bin', 'daily_20200623.bin', 'daily_20200630.bin', 'daily_20200707.bin', 'daily_20200714.bin', 'daily_20200721.bin', 'daily_20200728.bin', 'daily_20200804.bin', 'daily_20200811.bin', 'daily_20200818.bin', 'daily_20200825.bin', 'daily_20200901.bin']
```

I want the end result to be python printing all the daily_.ctl files whose file name matches a daily_.bin file. I will be executing code on the daily_.ctl files specifically and I want to see if there's an easier way to loop through each ctl_file to show me which ones have a matching binary file rather than me looking through each one myself. The first 14 characters of only some of the daily_.ctl files will have a matching daily_.bin file with the same first 14 characters. These are the ctl_files I need printed. I am a novice python user so I'm not sure how to get started, I am only using python as part of an ArcGis project for work. I'm using python shell 2.7.14

Answer (score 0):

You could split on the `.` and keep the first element effectively removing the extensions.  Then it's a matter of checking which file name from ctl is in bin.

```
[x for x in ctl_files if x.split('.')[0] in [i.split('.')[0] for i in bin_files]]
```